# How to I create a share button+count that counts only shares on my WP website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to add a share button with a share counter that actually counts shares. 
All I find are ones that sums all share and likes together. 
I Googled for more than 3 hours looking for an actual code that works, and nothing, I haven't found a code on the Facebook developer website.

Can somebody help me solve my problem? 
Thank you.

This is my share code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>?" title="Share on Facebook." onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwin', 'width=500, height=200'); return false;" >
    <img src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/buttons-sm2l.jpg" /> 
</a>
```

What we see here is a custom share button to facebook. The img tag is for the image share button.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights

or
what you could do is add a function in java-script script/ajax user clicks like button-> your code increments a counter in your database then completes the query

Comment: the JavaScript thing isn't an option for me. I want something that is linked to facebook itself.. 

I didn't understand what I should do with the first link

Answer (score 0):

You can create facebook share button from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

You can also see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mijoemathew/5wJju/)

In the `jsfiddle` demo change:

- data-href="https://testdomine.com" to your page link dynamically to get exact share count on each page.
- data-width="500px" to change the width of share button

The count depends on the url provided here. Hope this will help.

Comment: Not so accurate. 


From what I found out, the count box that the Facebook button generator creates gives you all the shares *and the likes* of the page link. 
And it doesn't fit 100% in my code. I am trying to create a custom button...